# Dendrogram in C#

Tags: c#, .net, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I implemented a version of AGNES (agglomerative clustering algorithm) in C#, but I am struggling to implement a dendrogram. I implemented a binary tree using a treeview component however I will need to build a "real" dendrogram for analysis of microarray gene expression data. I could not find any dendrogram component in .NET (R and Python have lots) and I don't have enough time to build one by drawing with GDI+. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Output the data to JSON and use D3.js in a web page.

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570

Depending on your application you can (i) render it to a file and use a separate web page (hosted on hard drive or IIS); (ii) render it dynamically to a web page through a self-hosted WebAPI controller; (iii) embed a web viewer control in your application.